# How to join multi tables with case statement?

Tags: sql

How to get data from multiple tables with case on one table, I tried like below but getting error.

```
select login.UserNname,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInIP,UserType.UserType,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime,
LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInVersion,CompanyRegistered.Comp_Name,

case 

when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is not null then CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),DATEDIFF (hour,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime ,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime ))+' Hours '+ 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),DATEDIFF (minute,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime ,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime )%60) +' Minutes' as Duration

when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is null then 'Running...' as Duration
end

from LastLoggedInDetails
join login on LastLoggedInDetails.LastLoggedUserId = login.RegistrationId
join UserType on LastLoggedInDetails.LastLoggedUserTypeId = UserType.UserTypeId
join CompanyRegistered on LastLoggedInDetails.RegCompanyId = CompanyRegistered.Comp_Id
```

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense. What was the error? Also, which RDBMS are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sysntax error after ending case and when iam joing to other tables then not showing its columns lists.

Comment: Your "AS" for column aliases has to be after the `END` of the `CASE` statement, not within each `WHEN`

Comment: Thanq Very much @Tom H Now I cleared my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select login.UserNname,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInIP,UserType.UserType,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime,
LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInVersion,CompanyRegistered.Comp_Name,

case 

when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is not null then CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),DATEDIFF (hour,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime ,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime ))+' Hours '+ 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),DATEDIFF (minute,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime ,LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime )%60) +' Minutes'
when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is null then 'Running...'
end as Duration

from LastLoggedInDetails
join login on LastLoggedInDetails.LastLoggedUserId = login.RegistrationId
join UserType on LastLoggedInDetails.LastLoggedUserTypeId = UserType.UserTypeId
join CompanyRegistered on LastLoggedInDetails.RegCompanyId = CompanyRegistered.Comp_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code for the `case`, formatted to be helpful:

```
case when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is not null
     then CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),
                  DATEDIFF(hour, LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime, LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime)
                 ) + ' Hours ' + 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),
                  DATEDIFF(minute, LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime,   
                           LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime
                          )%60
                  ) +' Minutes' as Duration
--------------------------------^
     when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is null
     then 'Running...' as Duration
end
```

Formatting the code makes the problem obvious:  `case` is an expression that can be named.  The individual results from each `then` are not named. So, try this:

```
(case when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is not null
      then CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),
                   DATEDIFF(hour, LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime, LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime)
                  ) + ' Hours ' + 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),
                   DATEDIFF(minute, LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedInTime,   
                            LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime
                           )%60
                   ) +' Minutes' 
      when LastLoggedInDetails.LoggedOutTime is null
      then 'Running...' 
 end) as Duration
```